# Computing unique identification keys in a quadtree / octree structure

Tags: c, tree, key

My program uses a tree structure in order to handle a huge amount of data. This tree structure can be two dimensional (quadtree) or three dimensional (octree).

Every tree node can be identified by a unique key. The following image shows four examples how these keys are created:

[image]

The keys are of type unsigned long and are therefore 64 bit long. The following keys shown in the image are the keys of the first and the last node:

```
k1 = 000000000000000000000000000000100
k2 = 000000000000000000000000000000111
k3 = 000000000000000000000000000001000
k4 = 000000000000000000000000000001011
```

These keys are getting bigger and bigger if I move from the top to the bottom of the tree since I compute them by doing: k = (k << DIM) + [0,1,2,3] in two dimensions.

Now I want to transform these keys to get "horizontal" keys. This means, that the keys are getting bigger and bigger if I move from left to the right within the tree.

To do that I use the tree level `lvl` which represents the depth, the maximum tree depth `max_lvl` which is in my case 31 in two dimensions and 21 and three dimensions and the dimension `D` which is 2 or 3.

```
k_new = k << D*(max_lvl - lvl)
```

Doing that I get with (D = 2, lvl = 1, max_lvl = 31)

```
k1_new = 010000000000000000000000000000000
k2_new = 011100000000000000000000000000000
k3_new = 100000000000000000000000000000000
k4_new = 101100000000000000000000000000000
```

Now the problem:

`k2_new` and `k3_new` are neighbor nodes and therefore their keys should almost be the same. In fact the "gab" should be decimal 1. However there is a huge gab between those two keys. This can be seen if I convert the binary number into a decimal number:

```
decimal(k2_new) =  8,070,450,532,247,928,832
decimal(k3_new) =  9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

I want to be able to compute the maximum node in such a way, that the gap between neighbor nodes (same level but different parent nodes) is equal to one. I want something like:

```
k1_new = 010000000000000000000000000000000
k2_new = 011111111111111111111111111111111
k3_new = 100000000000000000000000000000000
k4_new = 101111111111111111111111111111111
```

which is for k2_new and k3_new:

```
decimal(k2_new) =  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
decimal(k3_new) =  9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

But how do I do that?

I tried the following (only pseudo code) which did not end in the desired result using a recursive tree walk:

```
    void tree_walk(treenode t, int level, unsigned long key){
        if(t != NULL){
            for(int i=0; i<DIM*DIM; i++){
                tree_walk(t->node[i], level+1, i + (key << DIM))
            }
            key_min = key << DIM * (max_lvl - lvl);

            key_max = (key+DIM*DIM-1) << DIM * (max_lvl - lvl);
            key_max = key_max + ~(~0L << DIM*(maxlvl-lvl));
        }
    }
```

Does someone see my error?

Comment: Note: "are of type unsigned long and are therefore 64 bit long" --> maybe - could be 32-bit.  Better to use `uint64_t` for a 64-bit unsigned

Comment: Does `k_new = k << D*lvl` work for you?

Comment: @chux No, it wouldn't generate the desired keys which are getting bigger horizontally (from left to right)